# How to show the projection graphically?

Tags: linear-algebra, projection

We need to find a formula for $T(a,b)$ , where T represents the projection on the y-axis along the line $L$ = { (s , s) for s belonging to $R$ } .

I got $T(a,b)$ as $T(a,b)$ = ($0$ , $b-a$) , but how to show this projection graphically ? 
Please help !

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by "projection on the y axis along the x-axis"?

Comment: A function T:V -> V is called the projection of W1 along W2 , if for x = x1 + x2 , x1 belonging to W1 and x2 belonging to W2 , we have T(x) = x1 . 
V , is a vector space and W1 , W2 subspaces of V . @KittyL

Comment: Thanks for explaining. Why is it not $T(a,b)=(0,b)$ then?

Comment: I'm so sorry .. just made an edit @KittyL

Comment: Thus we write x = (a , b) = (0 , b-a) + (a , a) ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this picture:

[image]

The dashed lines are drawn from the end of the vector toward the two directions, each one parallel to the other direction. So you make a parallelogram with the two directions.